# Python и http авторизация

Tags: python, авторизация

Как реализовать на Python авторизацию на странице, например, почты, чтобы узнать, сколько новых писем в ящике?

Answer (score 3):

Если это веб-страница, посмотрите, какой метод передачи данных использует форма авторизации (скорее всего, POST), отправьте данные HTTP-запросом через urllib2, с полученным HTML делайте что хотите.
Но вообще, если вам именно почту посмотреть, подключайтесь через POP3/IMAP к ящику, а авторизация ради писем через HTTP - это как гланды через не то место:)

Answer (score 0):

видел такое на ютубе, но не для мыла.
п.с. у меня кстати не получается так.

```
url = 'http://сайт.ру/логин.пхп' #к примеру

def auth(():
    session = requests.Session()
    payload = {
        'email':'////',
        'password':'/////'
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```